# How to find element based on data-attribute with this existing JS code example?

Tags: javascript

I want to target a specified div, but my example for now is only when it has an id.
I want to use pure Javascript

current:

```
<div id="my_id">hello</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('my_id').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',
    '<h3>text</h3>');
</script>
```

my case:

```
<div data-foo="bar">hello</div>
<div data-foo="club">hi</div>
```

How can I target the div that has the `bar` data-foo attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) alongside [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
document.querySelector("div[data-foo='bar']").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',
'<h3>text</h3>');
```

```html
<div data-foo="bar">hello</div>
<div data-foo="club">hi</div>
```